# Set 'editor-field' value in ASP MVC3 View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to give a field in my ASP MVC view the default value of the current date, but I cannot figure out how to do this in the View code. I need to allow this to be field to be update-able, however, since it will not always be the most current date. Any suggestions?

```
    <div class="M-editor-label">
        Effective Date
    </div>
    <div class="M-editor-field">            
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EffectiveDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EffectiveDate)
    </div>
```

EDIT

I have tried to give this field a default value in the Model like so

```
    private DateTime? effectiveDate = DateTime.Now;

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EffectiveDate
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now; } 
        set { effectiveDate = value; }
    }
```

However the `get` property gives me the following error message:

`Monet.Models.AgentTransmission.EffectiveDate.get must declare a body because it is not marked abstract extern or partial`

^ (Monet is the name of the project, and AgentTransmission is the name of the current Model I am working in, of which EffectiveDate is a property.)

SECOND EDIT

Per the suggestion in one of the answers below I set the constructor as such, however this still put a blank value in the field when the View was rendered.

```
    public AgentTransmission()
    {
        EffectiveDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

THIRD EDIT

Fixed the above issue with the `get`, posting the entirety of what I have in my controller so far.

```
    public AgentTransmission()
    {
        EffectiveDate = DateTime.Today;
        this.AgencyStat1 = new HashSet<AgencyStat>();
    }

    //Have tried with an without this and got the same results
    private DateTime? effectiveDate = DateTime.Today;

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EffectiveDate
    {
        get { return effectiveDate; }  
        set { effectiveDate = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Trying to understand... Are you saying you want to default or override the value of model.EffectiveDate to be DateTime.Today?

Comment: I want to default it to today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by, as the other answers have suggested, by creating a default value in the constructor like so

```
public AgentTransmission()
{
    EffectiveDate = DateTime.Today;
    this.AgencyStat1 = new HashSet<AgencyStat>();
}

private DateTime? effectiveDate;

public Nullable<System.DateTime> EffectiveDate
{
    get { return effectiveDate; }  
    set { effectiveDate = value; }
}
```

And adding this code to the specific page in the constructor to initialize the new object ;

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new AgentTransmission());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the default value in the constructor for the model class. Something like this:

```
class YourClass {
  public DateTime EffectiveDate {get;set;}

  public YourClass() {
    EffectiveDate = DateTime.Today;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thought this would work, but displayed nothing in the view. I've stepped through, and checked the `locals` window and looks like it still has a value of `null` when the View is rendered.